# regex_replace on string for string match and not substring match

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, regex-replace

This:

```
words = words.withColumn('value_2', F.regexp_replace('value', '|'.join(stopWords), ''))
```

works fine for substrings.

However, I have a stop word 'a' and as a result 'was' becomes 'ws'. I only want to see it on 'A' or 'a', and leave was as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place word boundaries around the alternation:

```
words = words.withColumn('value_2', F.regexp_replace('value', '\\b(' + '|'.join(stopWords) + ')\\b', ''))
```